# Jquery-How to clear the entered data when i change the drop down value not for default item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Here, I have one drop down with 3 value like 0, 1, 2 and 5 text boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/j4JZX/3/

when i change the drop down value, from credit card to purchase card or purchase card to credit card that time only i need to clear the entered data. not for from 0 to 1 or 0 to 2.

**Added more:**

I have 3 drop down value as 0, 1 and 3. And 5 more text boxes are there. By default the drop down value is 0, now i enter the data for that text boxes and i change the drop down value 0 to 1 or 2. This time shouldn't happen no more changes on those textboxes value. If i select the drop down value from 1 to 2 or 2 to 1, this time data should be clear.

Can anyone help on this required?

Comment: The exact logic you're trying to achieve isn't clear from the question, but you can clear a value in a text `input` by using `$("#myInput").val("");`

Comment: check. do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/j4JZX/4/

Comment: Where is referenceID ? if you add an id to your select "referenceID" and use this $('#referenceID').change(function(){ $("input[type='text']").val(""); }); it will clear your inputs on change

Comment: @Gopesh please check my updated description.

Comment: @pluda i updated the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the previously selected value, compare it with the currently selected value, if there is a transition `2 -> 1` or `1 -> 2`, clean up your textboxes:

```
 $(function(){
     var previousValue = $("select").val();
     $('select').change(function() {
         var currentValue = $(this).val();
         if (previousValue == 2 && currentValue == 1 
             || previousValue == 1 && currentValue == 2) {
           $("input.textbox").val("");
         }
         previousValue = currentValue;
     });
 })​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4JZX/7/).

Comment: This solution works.. but if he added more options it wouldn't be too good

Comment: @Joao This is fine for me. Thanks your help. I have one more scenario. Here everything is fine like from value 1 to 2 or 2 to 1. Now from 1 to 0 again to 2 or from 2 to 0 again 1 this time also i need to clear. Is this possible? Can you give your positive answer please?

Comment: @Sivasenthil: Add the conditions `previousValue == 1 && currentValue == 0 || previousValue == 2 && currentValue == 0`. But what you are saying here is that basically, everything but the `0 -> *` transitions get cleaned, right? If it is, you can simply change the condition to `if (previousValue != 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j4JZX/5/

What i did is clear all the textboxes on change of html select change event

Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `select` element to choose a payment type, you can just reset the values of your **textbox class** when the values changes. You can use the `focus` callback to save the previously selected value. It's also probably a good idea to **remove the default selection** once you start making selections. Why would anyone need to choose **-Select-** as a payment option?

```
var previous;
$("select").focus(function () {
    previous = this.value; // Store the value before change.
}).change(function() {
    $("select option[value='-1']").remove(); // Remove default selection.
    if(previous != -1) { // If the last value wasn't -1 ('-Select-')
      $(".textbox").val(""); // Then clear all textboxes.
    }
});
```

Comment: this is fine without condition.

Comment: My answer was for your **original** question. My changes address your current request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the last value to track changes as suggested by @Joao. Instead of having a global variable, You can have an attribute of the select element to store the last selected value. like this:

```
$(function(){
 $("select").attr('rel', $("select").val());

 $('select').change(function() {
     previousValue = $("select").attr('rel');

     var currentValue = $(this).val();
     if (previousValue != 0) {
       $("input.textbox").val("");
     }
     $("select").attr('rel', currentValue);
 });
})​
```